# How can I use Sketch App to make dxf files (for laser cutting, cnc, etc)?

Tags: export, sketch-app

I'd like to design some stuff for laser cutting, and am familiar with Sketch App.  Unfortunately, I can't simply hand over an SVG and expect it to work, and have been advised to shoot for a dxf file or something that will convert easily to one.

How can I work in Sketch App to produce dxf files?

EDIT: I've found that one can download inkscape and use it to convert svg to dxf, then you can check the results in LibreCad.  But I'm not having great results yet, generally only one layer shows up.

EDIT 2: It seems to need to be said, I'm not working on high precision machining.  I'm etching out some simple graphic design.

Comment: Generally its not enough to be a DXF file. it also has to be well formed DXF. Now since graphic design apps work on beziers its a bit problematic. So anybody asking you a DXF is trying to avert a problem that can not be averted even if its turned to DXF since your application of choice already messed things up. So whatever problem they have they will continue to have even if you supply a DXF file.

Comment: You can also not design the same way to lasercutting as you design for print. You cant just layer stuff on top since the laser is not a printer, it does not do hiding.

Comment: So you're saying nobody has written the code to do this yet?  I'm a developer, so I know enough to say for sure that computers can do line math and conversions.

Comment: No, almost invariably the laser operator can read SVG or PDF, but does not want to. What I'm saying is that they want a DXF file. They want this because the DXF file has a better primitives for this kind of work, so they work under the illusion that you submit them a proper re designed DXF file instead of converting it. See even if you convert the file to DXF it will exhibit the exact problems they want to avoid by asking a DXF file. Making your file a DXF does not fix the fact that you original file does not have the features the laser operator idealy wants.

Comment: So, nobody has yet made the code to convert the bad lines to equatable good lines?

Comment: That is becasue its not possible. Software that tries to do this exist but almost invariably you dont want to rely on one since the result are quite often not what users want. Simply its a question of graphic design having simplified primitives (lower order functions), and converting them to more descriptive primitives is not possible without making assumptions. Assumptions which can fail, and me as a manufacturer am not ready to risk cutting material that costs 1000-300€ on something that is maybe what the client will pay for.

Comment: So the software for it exists, it's just kind of lame.  I'll see if I can write my own.  Flattening an entire svg seems like a hassle, but converting a bezier curve to like sections is literally how they are drawn on the screen.  It's well documented math.

Comment: Thats not the problem, the cad operator wants the primitives in actual circilar arcs and b-splines. But also wants a higher accuracy of positioning than what your application is supplying. I can assure you they can convert the file you have to DXF that's not the problem they just want you to design it more properly whith info not available in your file. Under no circumstances do they want you to make linear segments out of beziers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95734/discussion-between-joojaa-and-seph-reed).